# How to return the miliseconds of a GetDate() function of T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
UPDATE       Player
SET          move = GETDATE()
```

and it return this:

```
09/12/2010 13:43:51
```

But I want the miliseconds. How can I do this?
My move column type is DateTime.
Thank you.

Comment: What data type is the column `move`? and what is the query you are using to get the output give by you?

Comment: the query I already said above. The column type is DateTime. I will update this information.

Comment: Add the table definition please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have no ideia why, but the solution is this:

```
SELECT        playerId, (SELECT        CONVERT(varchar(23), GETDATE(), 121) AS Expr1) AS Expr1
FROM            Player
```

Answer (score 1):

`GETDATE()` does give milliseconds

If move does not have milliseconds stored then it:

- it isn't datetime
- it one of the SQL Server 2008 types with incorrect precision

Edit: if column is datetime then it's probably the client tools are not showing milliseconds

What does `SELECT * FROM Player show` in a query pane? Are you using the SSMS grids: these use your client settings which will lose milliseconds

Comment: how can I change that client tools please?
the select query return the same thing I posted. I tested it.

Comment: yes, I am using grid, but I tested changing to text, and still the same.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a DateTime then it will have stored a fractional part, but you will need to format the output to show them.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime data type by default has milliseconds information

```
declare @myDate datetime;
Select @myDate=getdate();
Select @myDate;
```

will output

```
2010-12-09 21:03:28.243
```

What needs to be checked is the `Select` query you are using to get the output of

```
09/12/2010 13:43:51
```

Moreover what version of MS-SQL are you using?

Comment: My Select query is this "select * from Player", and it return this:
"09/12/2010 13:43:51". I am using visual studio 2010, so I guess my sql used is 2008.

Comment: @Alan: Please try running the same query from the SQL Management Studio (Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 -> SQL Server Management Studio) and confirm you are getting the same output.

Comment: I can't test it. I only have managment 2005, which doesn't allow =/

Comment: Well, I tested with ADO.NET, and the milisseconds return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Edit & Snip : Just a hunch, but if you are using SQL 2000 Query Anaylyzer the setting Tools-Options-Connections Use regional settings when displaying number, date and times might be useful

Comment: my column is really only "datetime"